# How to import or inject ParseFilePipe in Nest.JS?

Tags: nestjs

```
import { ParseFilePipe } from '@nestjs/common';
```

*'"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member named 'ParseFilePipe'. Did you mean 'ParseFloatPipe'?*

The docs say all pipes are in `/common`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not mentioned in the docs, but these are only available in NestJS 9.x.

Answer (score 1):

`yarn add @nestjs/common`

Looks like the install was corrupted for me. All other pipes worked but not this one, very unsettling.

Comment: The install is very unlikely to be corrupted. What's more likely is that you inadvertently followed @A.C. 's answer and updated nestjs/common to a version which included this pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The ParseFilePipe and FileTypeValidator are available only from Nest v9, however you can update just the common package without update the nest core.

```
yarn add @nestjs/common
```

I'm running Nest v8 with common package from v9.